# a script to shutdown the other pc in the network if they donot respond to ping command

Tags: command-line, scripts, selinux

A (program)script to shutdown the other linux operated Computer in the same network , if they do not respond to ping command otherwise a message to show that they do not respond.
please help me

Comment: In what way are you connected to this other system on your network? If you're not logged on to it, you cannot issue commands to it. If you are logged on to it in any way that would allow you to issue commands to shut it down, you're already doing a heck og a lot more communicating that a simple ping response.

Answer (score 2):

If your question could be rephrased "how do I remotely signal a machine to shut down after I've determined that it can't react to remote signals?" then the answer is "You Can't."